# *file_get_contents* No obtiene todos los datos de un .txt

Tags: php

Estoy tratando de obtener el contenido de un archivo TXT
Para ello estoy usando el método `file_get_contents`
Tomando el archivo, lo guardo en una variable, y lo muestro con `var_export()`
Todo simple, todo ok, pero acá esta el problema.
El texto a leer contiene una fecha y hora, ej:

```
//Contenido del Archivo: 'fecha.txt'
2020-11-02 10:10:23
```

Obtenemos su contenido, lo guardamos, y lo mostramos

```
$txtDiario = 'fecha.txt';
$cdiario = file_get_contents($txtDiario);
echo var_dump($cdiario)."</br>";
```

Y por alguna razón, el resultado es el siguiente:

```
'string(10) "2020-11-02"
```

**No aparece la Hora, ni minuto, ni segundo que contiene el archivo.**
Sigo buscando por que sucede esto, pero lo dejo acá para ver si alguien sabe del tema ya.

Comment: gracias, no costo tanto...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrado el problema:

Anteriormente estaba usando `fopen()`, y el problema era el permiso:
Le estaba pasando `w+`, lo que significa:

```
Apertura para lectura y escritura;
coloca el puntero al fichero al principio del fichero y trunca el fichero a longitud cero. 
Si el fichero no existe se intenta crear.
```

Entonces, probé a cambiarlo por `r`, lo cual solucionó todos los problemas.

```
Apertura para sólo lectura; coloca el puntero al fichero al principio del fichero.
```

Comment: ¿El problema se resolvió? ¿Esta es la solución? Si es así no plantees dudas en la respuesta. Si el problema no se ha resuelto edita la pregunta indicando en que situación se encuentra el problema luego de haber intentado cambios. Si el problema se resolvió y surgió otro problema colateral, abre una nueva pregunta con el nuevo problema. Es importante comprender que este sitio no funciona como un foro, sino sobre preguntas concretas con soluciones concretas, con la idea de que si mañana alguien más tiene un problema similar la solución pueda ayudarle a resolverlo.

Comment: Quieres que quite lo que está en negritas ?

Comment: Quiero saber si el problema que planteas en la pregunta se resolvió y cuál es la solución. Las respuestas son para eso, no para plantear nuevas dudas como si fuese el hilo de un foro. Stackoverflow no funciona como los foros. Si resolviste el problema, pon el código final con el cual lo resolviste para que otros usuarios con el mismo problema puedan verlo. No sé si me explico: el sentido de este sitio es que tu problema y la solución al mismo pueda servir también a otros.

Comment: "Encontrado el problema:" -- " ... lo cual solucionó todos los problemas.".

Comment: Si deseas que quite lo que está en negritas, pues bien.